# Circuit breaker system standard

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker

UL 489 certifies only the clearance, but is there a standard specifying how energized bars are connected to the circuit breakers?

Or is matching brands for circuit breaker boxes and circuit breakers themselves the only way to make sure they're compatible?

Comment: Is this question specific to industrial, commercial, or residential installations?

Comment: @wallyk Residential, but I'd be curious to know about others as well.

Answer (score 2):

Circuit breakers are not interchangeable amongst manufacturers or even within manufacturer lines (many of which are acquisitions).   There is no effort by regulatory agencies to do so.  There is little effort by manufacturers to do so, except that a few manufacturers make breakers for other people's service panels.

Answer (score 0):

UL 489 covers the circuit breakers themselves -- UL 67 covers the actual panelboard the breakers are installed into.

To your actual question, follow the labeling on the panelboard that specifies which breakers you can use (it'll be a list of letter-abbreviations), or on a UL Classified replacement breaker if you are using one of those.

Comment: What kind of labeling?